# Facebook Share Button Doesn't Work

Tags: jquery, html, css, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I get this code from facebook developers: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Your Website Title</title>
    <!-- You can use Open Graph tags to customize link previews.
    Learn more: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters -->
    <meta property="og:url"           content="http://www.your-domain.com/your-page.html" />
    <meta property="og:type"          content="website" />
    <meta property="og:title"         content="Your Website Title" />
    <meta property="og:description"   content="Your description" />
    <meta property="og:image"         content="http://www.your-domain.com/path/image.jpg" />
</head>
<body>

    <!-- Load Facebook SDK for JavaScript -->
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>(function(d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
      js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1";
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

    <!-- Your share button code -->
    <div class="fb-share-button" 
        data-href="http://www.your-domain.com/your-page.html" 
        data-layout="button_count">
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Nothing happen, no button appear... What's wrong?

[Live Code on Code Pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QEbROy)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was ADBLOCK, it was hiding the div...

Answer (score 0):

It does not appear that an actual button element has been added. Is that all of the code? Something like 
''button type="button">Share on Facebook

Answer (score 0):

Okay so it all appears to be there, you just need to add an actual button. You have the code and link for one, but not the element itself. [how to add a button via W3C](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_button.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You left out this part: "Step 3: Place this code wherever you want the plugin to appear on your page":

```
<div class="fb-share-button" data-href="https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/" data-layout="button_count" data-mobile-iframe="false"></div>
```

The `data-href` value needs to be your own link.